# Copying values into an empty tensor

Tags: python, tensor

I have created a tensor of a specific size, namely C=[4, 3, 40]. I want to copy values from previous tensors into this tensor.

I want to copy all the values from tensor A = [4, 3] (so using this tensor completely) and only values from the 2nd dimension from tensor B = [4, 40, 1] (so only the 40 values). A and B are both FloatTensors.

I have tried:

```
ten_size = torch.zeros(4, 3, 40)
```

But this makes a tensor of all zeroes (obviously). I do not have any idea how to extract the specific values from tensors A and B and input it into ten_size, so that I don't have an all-zero tensor.

I then tried

`sec_dim = torch.clone(x_t[1])` which gives me a tensor of size [40,1]. Is there a way I can create a tensor from these values and tensor A of size [4,3] to get a tensor of size `[4,3,40]`?

Is this possible? Or is more information needed to answer this question? Also I am using pytorch

Thanks :)

Comment: Please provide code samples you have tried with details about data types you use.

Comment: Is this okay Alex? I've edited it now. Thanks

Comment: You are trying to copy 4x3 + 40 = 52 elements to a tensor having size (4x3x40 =) 480 elemens. How do you exactly want to arrange the values?

Answer (score 1):

PyTorch tensor has clone method that seems to do what you need: [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.clone.html)

To copy only second dimension:

```
A = torch.zeros(4, 3, 40)
B = torch.clone(A[0,:,0])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This method scraps all the values from tensor A and makes them 0. Maybe I didn't make this clear in the question and I apologise for this!! But my issue is that I need to have all the values from Tensor A of dimension [4,3] and also the values from dimension 2 from Tensor B.Using clone was useful to extract these values, so thank you! I will rephrase my question however as I feel I have been misunderstood.. Thank you I appreciate your help. :)